# php file_get_contents() using it within the child file

Tags: php

Bit strange this, but ideally I want to do something within my index page like:

> file_get_contents("file1.php");

then within file1.php I want to get contents of file2.php

> file_get_contents("file2.php");

So obviously when index is calling file1 this works, but when file1 is calling file2 it gets the files contents but it's not executing any php that's withiin file2.

Should also mention the reason I'm not using includes is becuase the files are being called remotely.

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Shane

Answer (score 3):

`file_get_contents` is to get a file's content as a string, so no code is executed.
If you want to call to execution a file from within another you must do an `include`/`include_once` or `require`/`require_once`, look [here](http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/archive/index.php/t-10271506.html) to see the differences.

This also works on remote files as long as you set the `allow_url_include` setting to true in php.ini and you use php >= 5.2.0 according to [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php)

Answer (score 2):

You must use include() or require(), file_get_contents gets content without parsing. Or eval() but it is bad idea.

Comment: I'm calling the files remotley

Comment: If you really must then use eval(file_get_contents("file1.php")), but I am sure there is other way to do what you intended, also use cURL for getting contents of remote files, it is much faster.

Comment: according to http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php: "you can use HTTP and FTP URLs with most of the functions that take a filename as a parameter. In addition, URLs can be used with the include(), include_once(), require() and require_once() statements (since PHP 5.2.0, allow_url_include must be enabled for these)"

Comment: Yes, but I don't think they will be parsed, you will include only the output of remote script. There is no way of reading source code unless it is plain text. @Shane make sure remote files are plain text (source code).